# Mocking Appender in unit testneeds to create an instance?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have some working unit tests using mockito and junit to check expected log entries are made.

Along these lines

```
@Mock
private final ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();

@Before
public void setup() {
    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyClass.class );
    logger.addAppender( listAppender );
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    ...

    // then
    verifyZeroInteractions( mockAppender );
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    ...

    // then
    verify( listAppender ).doAppend( ArgumentMatchers.argThat( argument -> {
        assertThat( argument.getMessage(), containsString( "Expected Message." ) );
        assertThat( argument.getLevel(), is( Level.ERROR ) );
        return true;
    } ) );
}
```

This is all good and works nicely.

It has exposed a weakness in my understanding of the Mocking framework though as I do not understand the Appender declaration

```
@Mock
private final ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
```

if I remove the @Mock annotation then the tests stop working because I can't verify -
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument(s) passed is not a mock!

but if it is a mock why am I creating a new instance  ?

if I remove the initialisation

```
@Mock
private final ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> mockAppender;
```

I get a build error

java: variable mockAppender not initialized in the default constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mock should not be assigned a value as this is for Mockito to do.  However Mockito doesn't set the value in the default constructor (as it can't) so it uses reflection to set it later.  On account of this, the mockAppender cannot be final.

So, you should remove the assignment and the final, so your declaration should look like this:

```
@Mock
private ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> mockAppender;
```